# Предупреждение компилятора quartus ii: Verilog HDL Compiler Directive warning at ...: text macro "b00" is undefined

Tags: verilog, fpga

Что значит предупреждение Critical Warning (10191): Verilog HDL Compiler Directive warning at chaincounter.v(30): text macro "b00" is undefined
Подобных варнингов очень много, они возникают при присвоении регистровым или целочисленным переменным значения в виде:

```
flagA = 2`b00;
clk_cnt=clk_cnt+1`b1;
```

На что это может повлиять?

Answer (score 0):

```
flagA = 2'b00;
clk_cnt=clk_cnt+1'b1;
```

попробуйте вот так. видимо вы перепутали символ " ` " и " ' "

Так же советую прочитать про блокирующие и неблокирующие присваивания 
https://marsohod.org/11-blog/85-veriloglesson5